# Cache Access from Message_Filter

Tags: message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the message_filter package, there is a cache function that allows you to store data for a temporary amount of time.  How would you access this cache properly?  I understand that the function in message_filter says for doing a callback but how would go and create this callback function for the cache.  I want to access different parts of the cache.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10417/cache-access-from-message_filter/) by [Kirielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/750/kirielson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are looking for that function:

`std::vector< MConstPtr > getInterval (const ros::Time &start, const ros::Time &end) const`

The callback is for new messages. I guess it's just there because it is a filter.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1